# Make Desktop App from incredibly small one page PHP site

Tags: php, html, css, widget

I have a very small site, that's almost used as a widget for certain employees, driven by a single index.php (plus CSS and font).

The site has a single search bar and button, and it searches by serial number in the database to get info on repairs of pieces of furniture.

This site is rarely used but I'd like to convert it, if possible, to a widget or desktop app, something of that nature. The bulk of the code is below:

```
if($_POST['submit']=="Continue"){

$sn = $_POST['sn'];
$sn = substr($sn, 0, 7);
if($sn == "" || strlen($sn) < 7 || !is_numeric($sn)){

    $data= '
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">      
                        <strong>Invalid Serial Number:</strong> 
                        Please try again.
                    </div>
    ';
}
else{
// Good serial number grab data.
    define("", "");

    define("", "");
    define("", "");
    define("", "");

    //Queries Here
    //
        $rs=odbc_exec($connectionstring,$sql);
    $rows = odbc_num_rows ($rs);

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {

    $frame=odbc_result($rs,"frameh");
    $desc=odbc_result($rs,"fdesch");
    $ship=odbc_result($rs,"dtshph");
    $prod=odbc_result($rs,"dtprdh");
}




if($rows == 1){
    $data = '
    <div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">SN: '.$sn.'</h3>
</div>
 <div class="panel-body">  
<ul>
    <li>Frame Number: '.$frame.'</li>
    <li>Frame Desc: '.$desc.'</li>
    <li>Produced Date: '.$prod.'</li>
    <li>Shipped Date: '.$ship.'</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

    ';

    }
    else{

    $data= '
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">      
                        <strong>Serial Number: '.$sn.' did not return any data</strong>                             
                    </div>
    ';

    }

    odbc_close($connectionstring);

}
}
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">Furniture </h1>
            <p class="text-center">Repair information.</p>

            <form method="post">
                <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Serial Number" Name="sn" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <p class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Continue">
                </form>
                </p>

                <div class="text-center" id="data">                 
<?php echo $data; ?>

                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You could probably do this with a framework like electron

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Actually trying nativfier with that now